# Image doesn´t shrink properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have background-image that when the browser ocuppies the whole screen, it displays properly. While I make the browser window smaller, the image shrinks up to a point, then suddenly it stops. This is what happens:

[image]

[image]

I only have a .CSS file that has:

```
.fondo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("src/assets/images/fondo.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

And the .html file has:

```
<div class="fondo img-fluid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this for responsive background images

```
Selector{
  background-image: url(images/background-photo.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
}
```

But sometimes i also face this issue
Then i use @media and define size manually at breakpoints or make background with  which is not possible in your case
All the best

Answer (score 0):

What you need is height in `vh` and width in `vw`:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/0o1p4j2n/6/) to playaround.

```css
.fondo {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/301/301");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fondo img-fluid"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be *background-position: center;*